# Data Purging in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, sql-delete, rowcount

I have the a Requirement where I have to Delete in batches in sql server , and also track the number of count affected in the end. My Sample Code is as Follows:

```sql
Declare @count int
Declare @deletecount int

set @count=0

While(1=1)
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRAN
DELETE TOP 1000 FROM --CONDITION

SET @COUNT = @COUNT+@@ROWCOUNT

IF (@@ROWCOUNT)=0
Break;

COMMIT

END CATCH

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK;
END CATCH

END

set @deletecount=@COUNT
```

Above Code Works fine, but how to keep track of `@deletecount` if Rollback happens in one of the batch.

Comment: What's the difference between `@count` and `@deletecount`? Why do you need them both?

Comment: What is the value in deleting in batches when your code performs the entire operation in a single transaction? Typically, one commits each batch individually when performing batched deletes to to avoid long-term locks and avoid growing the transaction log during the operation. The actual number of deleted rows will always be zero after an error because all batches are rolled back in the `CATCH` block so you could just add `SET @COUNT = 0;` in the `CATCH` block.

Comment: @gvee variable count is to keep the track of deleted records inside the while loop and Once loop is finished I am taking that value in new variable DeleteCount for further processing. I could have used variable count itself for further processing but I preferred storing it in new variable. I want to know how to track total delete count if such scenario happens ie Batch 1- Success, Batch 2 Rollback ,Batch 3 Success.

Comment: @DanGuzman that;s what I am thinking...What the point in Single Commit while Deleting in batches..if any one batch fails everything will be rolled back.
I need to capture the Count in scenario where Batch 1- Success, Batch 2 Rollback ,Batch 3 Success.

Comment: @jayeshkshirsagar, there will never be a batch 3 with your script since it will stop following an error in batch 2.

Comment: @DanGuzman I am not breaking the While Loop after the 2nd Batch Failure, Its Just Rollback.My Data deletion plan is While Loop + Batch of 1000.I need the final count outside the while loop.

Comment: @jayeshkshirsagar , I see. But note you last iteration will leave an open transaction after the `break`. Since `@COUNT` is incremented only after a successful `DELETE`, `@deletecount` will only include successfully deleted rows so you are good there.

Answer (score 1):

Some potential issues with the code :

> 1. while loop never exits/breaks

```
declare @tbl table(foo bit); --deleting from an empty table
declare @COUNT int; 
declare @iteration int = 0;

While(1=1)
BEGIN
    --loop safety net
    if @iteration >= 100
    begin
        break --exit after 100 iterations
    end
    select @iteration = @iteration+1

    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE TOP (1000) FROM @tbl; --@tbl is empty

        SET @COUNT = @COUNT+@@ROWCOUNT;-- <-- this always sets @@rowcount = 1

        IF (@@ROWCOUNT)=0 -- ... so this can never be 0 --> will never exit the loop
        Break;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

END --end while

select @iteration as iterations;
```

> 2. Open transaction at the end of the batch

```
declare @tbl table(foo bit); --<-- empty table
declare @COUNT int;
declare @myrowcount int; 
declare @iteration int = 0;


While(1=1)
BEGIN
    --loop safety net
    if @iteration >= 100
    begin
        break --exit after 100 iterations
    end
    select @iteration = @iteration+1

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN --<-- transaction begins on each iteration
        
        DELETE TOP (1000) FROM @tbl; --@tbl is empty
        
        set @myrowcount = @@rowcount;
        
        SET @COUNT = @COUNT+@myrowcount;

        IF (@myrowcount)=0
        Break; --<-- if this breaks... transaction is neither committed nor rolledback

        COMMIT --<-- commited on each iteration, when no error
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK --<-- or rolled back on each iteration error
    END CATCH

END --end while

select @iteration as iterations, @@trancount as open_transactions;

rollback transaction;
```

> 3. loop keeps trying to delete the same erroneous batch (over and over again) and never exits

```
create table parent (id int primary key clustered);
create table child (parentid int references parent(id));
go

--some parents
insert into parent(id)
select top (200) row_number() over(order by @@spid)
from sys.all_objects;
--and a child
insert into child(parentid) values (75)
go

declare @COUNT int; 
declare @myrowcount int;
declare @errormsg nvarchar(max);
declare @iteration int = 0;


While(1=1)
BEGIN
    --loop safety net
    if @iteration >= 100
    begin
        break --exit after 100 iterations
    end
    select @iteration = @iteration+1

    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE TOP (10) t --changed the batch size..for the example
        from (select top (10000) * from parent order by id) as t;
        set @myrowcount = @@rowcount;
        
        SET @COUNT = @COUNT+@myrowcount;

        IF (@myrowcount)=0
        Break;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        select @errormsg = isnull(@errormsg, '') + error_message();
    END CATCH

END --end while

select @iteration as iterations, @errormsg as errormsg;

--some parents have been deleted (8th batch kept failing, there is an fk to parent 75)
select *
from parent
go
drop table child
drop table parent
go
```

You could rectify all the above issues...(last one, to skip erroneous batches being a bit more "difficult"), by implementing logic in the where clause (eg. exclude rows which are referenced etc) according to your model. Trying to implement a straight deletion, without any rules, and skipping failures makes it a bit harder.

Just an example: when a batch fails, after 3 attempts, take another deletion route. Since each deletion is atomic, transactions are not really needed here (besides, if the batch is called from a parent module, a plain ROLLBACK in the batch would "invalidate" any transactions opened in the parent module, before the batch execution)

```
create table parent (id int primary key clustered);
create table child (parentid int references parent(id));
go

--some parents
insert into parent(id)
select top (200) row_number() over(order by @@spid)
from sys.all_objects;
--and two children
insert into child(parentid) values (75), (115) --, (9), (18) --: add 9 and 18 and nothing gets deleted, alternative route in the example does not work
go


declare @COUNT int;
declare @myrowcount int; 
declare @iteration int = 0;
declare @errormsg nvarchar(max);
declare @ierrorcnt int=0;

declare @deletedids table(id int);
declare @lastsuccessfullydeletedid int = 0;

select @COUNT = 0;
While(1=1)
BEGIN
    --loop safety net
    if @iteration >= 100
    begin
        break --exit after 100 iterations
    end
    select @iteration = @iteration+1

    BEGIN TRY
        
        --when 10 consecutive errors in a single iteration..just quit the loop
        if @ierrorcnt >= 10
        begin
            break;
        end
        
        BEGIN TRAN --<-- transaction begins on each iteration
        
        if @ierrorcnt >= 3 --when 3 consecutive errors in the iteration..try to bypass the current batch
        begin
    
            delete top (10) t
            output deleted.id into @deletedids(id)
            from (select top (10) * from (select top (2*10) * from parent where id > @lastsuccessfullydeletedid order by id) as a order by id desc) as t
    
            select @myrowcount = count(*), @lastsuccessfullydeletedid = max(id)
            from @deletedids;
            
            delete from @deletedids;
        end
        else
        begin
            DELETE TOP (10) FROM parent where id > @lastsuccessfullydeletedid;
            set @myrowcount = @@rowcount; 
        end
        
        SET @COUNT = @COUNT+@myrowcount;
        
        COMMIT --<-- commited on each iteration, when no error
        
        IF (@myrowcount)=0 and @ierrorcnt = 0
        Break;
        
        set @ierrorcnt = 0; --everything ok, set iteration error counter to 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK --<-- or rolled back on each iteration error
        if @ierrorcnt = 0
        begin
            select @errormsg = isnull(@errormsg, '') +';'+ error_message();
        end
        set @ierrorcnt = @ierrorcnt + 1; --error, increase the iteration error counter
        
    END CATCH

END --end while

select @iteration as iterations, @@trancount as open_transactions;
select @iteration as iterations, @errormsg as errormsg;

--some parents have been deleted
select * /*2 failed batches, 20 rows left*/
from parent

select @COUNT as [count/deleted] --<--this is also the deleted count

go
drop table child
drop table parent
go
```

..without any errors, in your original code, @count = @deletedcount

```
declare @tbl table(foo int); --<-- empty table
insert into @tbl(foo)
select top (100000) row_number() over(order by @@spid)
from sys.all_objects as a
cross join sys.all_objects as b;

--batch 1000, max iterations for the @tbl count
declare @maxiterations int;
select @maxiterations = 1+count(*) / 1000
from @tbl

declare @COUNT int;
declare @deletedcount int;
declare @myrowcount int; 
declare @iteration int = 0;


select @COUNT = 0, @deletedcount = 0;

While(1=1)
BEGIN
    --loop safety net
    if @iteration >= @maxiterations
    begin
        break --exit after @maxiterations
    end
    select @iteration = @iteration+1;

    BEGIN TRY
        
        BEGIN TRAN
        
        DELETE TOP (1000) FROM @tbl
        where foo%5 = 0 ; 
        
        set @myrowcount = @@rowcount;
        
        SET @COUNT = @COUNT+@myrowcount;
        set @deletedcount = @deletedcount + @myrowcount;

       COMMIT 
       
        IF @myrowcount=0
        Break;
 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK 
    END CATCH

END --end while

select @iteration as iterations, @@trancount as open_transactions;
select @count as _count, @deletedcount as deletedcount;
```